# MySQL/Linux: Custom stopword file - permission denied

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions, full-text-search

I'm trying to set my own **stopword list** for MySQL (5.1.54) fulltext index, but encountered problems with configuration. I tried the following steps:

1. I did set system variable in */etc/mysql/my.cnf* by adding line:

   ```
   ft_stopword_file = "/home/buli/stopwords.txt"
   ```
2. I created file */home/buli/stopwords.txt* with words that should be ignored
3. Now when I restart MySQL using *sudo service mysql restart* there is entry in */var/log/mysql/error.log* saying:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/home/buli/stopwords.txt' not found (Errcode: 13)
   111218 19:07:18 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
   111218 19:07:18 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
   ```

Running *perror 13* translates it as **permission denied** problem. The file however exists and I even gave it full permissions:

```
    $ ls -l /home/buli/stopwords.txt
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 buli buli 6 2011-12-18 18:41 /home/buli/stopwords.txt
```

Could there be any other, mysql-specific reason for this error to happen (as file permissions seems ok)?

Comment: What about `/home/buli`? It looks like someone's home directory so it's probably not public by default.

Comment: The mysql user cannot read into your home directory. By default, home directories are generally 0700. Move your file to a more public spot, like /opt, /usr/local or /etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running MySQL on a distro that uses AppArmor, chroot etc. to secure it?

For AppArmor you have to update /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld (or similar), for chroot you have to copy the file.

Best thing is to put the stopword file below the data directory and give a realtive path only.

Comment: This seems to be the case! Putting stopword file into one of directories defined in the file made MySQL load without errors. I wasn't even aware of AppArmor. Thanks for a quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

One: **NEVER GIVE 777 RIGHTS TO ANY FILE**.

Two: the problem is certainly that the user running MySQL cannot enter `/home/buli`. If you need to access a file, you must also have at least the execution permission on all directories leading to that file (yes, read permission is not even needed).

Comment: I'll definitely look more carefully into unix permissions :) Moving file to more accessible directories however didn't solve the case this time, AppArmor reconfiguration did. Thanks for a reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1. Search my.cnf or my.ini
# whereis my.cnf
or
#mysql --verbose --help | less

Step 2. Edit my.cnf file
#sudo vim /etc/my.cnf

# Add stop word file and file should be exist
ft_stopword_file="/usr/mysql/stop_words.txt"  ## You can give any path where you put your stop file

Step 3-> Restart mysql
#sudo service mysqld  restart

Step 3-> Login my sql
#mysql -u root -p
mysql -> use mydatabase_name;

mysql-> show variables like 'ft_%';

Variable_name            | Value

ft_stopword_file      /usr/mysql/stop_words.txt`enter code here`

Step -> 5 :- Repair full-test table file

 REPAIR TABLE tablename QUICK

mysql-> REPAIR TABLE products QUICK;
```